# C# How to send additional information in http response when returning partial view from MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpresponse, partial-views

I have a c# MVC partial view that returns back `HTML`, I want to add some more information to it i.e. Client side we want to know which product category it was?

The controller looks like:

```
public ActionResult Product(id)
        {
            Product product = _productBL.GetProduct(id);
            return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/Product.cshtml", product);
        }
```

How can I send such additional information in `http response` along with `Partial View Action Result`? Can i use response headers?

Comment: Can it not be a simple ViewModel with Product class and addition info you need to add and pass to PartialView

Answer (score 0):

Well, your response is a html text. One quick solution, for simple, unsecured data, will be to include a hidden field your response. You can create one in your Product.cshtml by using @Html.Hidden or @Html.HiddenFor helpers.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public ActionResult Product(id)
    {
        Product product = _productBL.GetProduct(id);
        return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/Product.cshtml", product, new ViewDataDictionary { Foo = "Weeeeeeee!!!" });
    }
```

Then just access it the same way you would normal access a viewbag item in your view

```
    @model YourApp.Product
    @{
        string displayName = ViewData["Foo"];
    }
```